# Daily temperature data portal globally

Tags: data, precipitation

Can anyone help me with a common website from where I can download historical climatic data on a daily basis?

PRISM gives only for US regions.

Comment: What country?  In any event I think this would be more on-topic at the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: Any country, Just need a common portal for all the countries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Open Data Stack Exchange](https://opendata.stackexchange.com) has an excellent community wiki question with links to many different sources of weather data: [Sources of weather data](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/10154/sources-of-weather-data)

Answer (score 0):

Look: https://www.wunderground.com/wundermap
It's possible to scrap data or to use api free for limited requests

Answer (score 0):

Historic climatic data  from all over the world can be downloaded from https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/cdo-web/ .